# Why is my Angular form custom validation not firing

Tags: angular

I have this form and validation function in the .ts :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(6),
            Validators.maxLength(40),
            this.checkPasswords.bind(this)
          ]
        ], 
        rePass: ['', [Validators.required, this.checkPasswords.bind(this)]],
        roles: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },
    );
  }
 
  get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;  
  }
  checkPasswords(): ValidatorFn {  
    let pass = this.form?.value.password;
    let confirmPass =  this.form?.value.rePass;
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null =>  {
      return( pass === confirmPass) ? null : {notSame: control.value};
    }
  }
```

And this is in my HTML:

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="f.rePass.errors?.notSame">Error</mat-error>
```

So the validation function is updating correctly but it is not firing a signal to the HTML template. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator function should take an `AbstractControl` and return `null` or an object indicating the error. You are supplying a function that receives no arguments and returns a validator function.

You should use something like this:

```js
checkPasswords(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {  
  let pass = this.form?.value.password;
  let confirmPass =  this.form?.value.rePass;
  return (pass === confirmPass) ? null : { notSame: control.value };
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use `bind` when using it, but rather this:

```js
rePass: ['', [Validators.required, c => this.checkPasswords(c)]],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears out a lot of questions. I used your answer, but I needed to change this.form?.value.password to this.form?.controls.password.value , because otherwise it wasn't taking the first input.